# Creating an if in a js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a code that filter all order history the user have but a want to create an if to just filter only the orders that I bought online (I have a variable that is 1 if is in the store and 2 if is online). How to i do the if?

```
filterOrderHistory: function() {
            $(".historyorder-state").on('click', function(){
                $('#filterOptions').show();
            });
            $('#filterOptions li').on('click', function() {
                var text = $(this).text();
                $('.tbl-shopping-history').html('<div class="form-spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>');
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    data: { state: $(this).attr('class').toUpperCase() },
                    dataType: "html",
                    url: '/impuls/store/components/order-history-table.jspf'
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    $('.tbl-shopping-history').html(data);
                    $('.historyorder-state').html(text+'<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>');
                    $('#filterOptions').hide();
                });
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Use `if` in the `done` function?

Comment: what is `data` inside done function? can you share that as well

Comment: if you can't send a filter value to the server in the AJAX request (which is likely to be the most efficient way, if the server supports that), then you'll have to filter it in the `done` once the response is received. Might be tricky though...it looks like your response data is in HTML format? If you control the server code, it would be better to implement filtering there.

Comment: I agree with ADyson, but alternatively if you can at least get the response data as JSON (a JS array) instead of HTML you could filter with `response.filter( fn )`. Depending on what your response `data` looks like, as Shubham asks, there could be a way to filter that; but you'd want to do that _before_ doing `$('.tbl-shopping-history').html(...)`